# Interacting with the past

Tags: quantum-states

I have a question about a Quantum Mechanics machine that should interact with the past, I can't find any flaws with it, but I just want to make sure.

The machine has a lot of facts about history, some true and some false, and the machine knows which one each fact is. It measures the spin of an electron, and if it has an up spin, it tells a true 'fact' and then a false 'fact', but if it has a down spin, it tells the a false 'fact' and then a true 'fact'. It does this several times so it will probably have both at least once. So until you check which one, the past is in a sense, in a quantum state of being one thing or another.

If this all stems from incredible stupidity, I'm really sorry, but if it doesn't, thanks in advance.

EDIT: To specify, the part where it 'interacts' with the past, is when you check which spin it is, so you *can* use a coin to do the same thing. In other words: each fact is true and false at the same time, so checking collapses and 'changes' the past.

Comment: But then the 'facts' that the machine has are not 'facts', if it is actually 'interacting' with the past. Replace you electron spin with a coin flip, and all you have is a machine that lies in a different order depending on heads or tails. Nothing about the past is 'interacted' with.

Comment: How can anything interact with the past? To interact with the past means being able to go back into the past and change it.

Comment: Except in special cases quantum systems don't remember the past uniquely, to begin with. The outcome of a measurement depends on the (classical/dissipative) measurement device and without measurement a quantum system is closed and won't tell you what state it is in. As a result we can force every quantum system to have one of many possible outcomes for any one of its past states. A good example for quantum systems that don't remember the past, at all, are radioactive decays. They are all independent of each other.

Answer (score 3):

> The machine has a lot of facts about history, some true and some false, and the machine knows which one each fact is.

Notice that the machine can do this without measuring any electrons. The machine cannot interact with the past; your lack of information about the spin of a particular information cannot verify or falsify "Bill Murray was the 16th President of the United States." The ability of the machine to record a fact as "true" or "false" in the first place is counterpoint to it being able to "interact with the past" or leave the past "in a quantum state of being one thing or another."

In fact, your machine is fully deterministic for a one-way time progression: The current state of the machine is a direct result of the past state of the machine and its environment, including the facts it stores, the electron spins it records and the outputs it gives.